# How to log HTTP exchanges (including the payloads) in spring-boot with spring-web

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is there any way to log complete HTTP exchanges (request + response including headers + payloads) in a spring-web REST service?

I have seen the [CommonsRequestLoggingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.html), but that only logs the request. Is there a matching CommonsResponseLoggingFilter? Or a different solution?

In Jersey this functionality is provided by [LoggingFeature](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.34/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html), you just need to enable it.

For the HTTP server I use the default Tomcat. There's [AccessLogValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.html), but that doesn't log the payload.

Ideally I would want something at spring-web level, similar to Jersey, so I don't have to worry about it if I switch from Tomcat to Jetty or Undertow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if spring have any build-in filter which help to log both request/response.

But you can write customize filter to do it.

```
@Component
public class CustomLoggingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
@Override
  public void doFilter(
      final ServletRequest req,
      final ServletResponse res,
      final FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    CachedBodyHttpServletRequest reqWrap = new CachedBodyHttpServletRequest(
        (HttpServletRequest) req);
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper resWrap = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(
        (HttpServletResponse) res);
    chain.doFilter(reqWrap, resWrap);
    resWrap.copyBodyToResponse();
  }
}
```

CachedBodyHttpServletRequest and ContentCachingResponseWrapper can help you to access headers/datas multiple time and do few logging without broken any datas.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingResponseWrapper.html